# Appending something to a list within a dict within a list in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am attempting to create a `list` of `dicts` which will have the following structure:

```
[
    {
        'id': '234nj233nkj2k4n52',
        'embedded_list': []
    },
    {
        'id': 'jb234bhj23423h4b4',
        'embedded_list': []
    },
    ...
]
```

Initially, this list will be empty.

What I need to be able to do is:

1. Check to see if a `dict` with a specific `id` exists in the list already
2. If a dict containing that `id` exists, append something to it's `embedded_list`
3. If a dict containing that `id` does not exist, create a dict, append it to the list.

I am aware of being able to test if a `dict` exists in a `list` based on something inside that `dict` using something like this:

```
extracted_dict = next((item for item in list if item['id'] == unique_id), None)
```

I am unsure of how to append something to a `list` within a `dict` within a `list` efficiently.  Is there an obvious way which I'm not seeing (probably)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you need a list of dictionaries? It seems that one dictionary with the structure `{id: list, id: list,...}` would be more suitable.

Comment: Order of items could matter, in this case a dict isn't an option. (Python 3 provides an OrderedDict (http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict))

Comment: @gecco: And 2.7 provides it too. And there is no indication of order mattering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data structure should be a dictionary of dictionaries in the first place:

```
{'234nj233nkj2k4n52': {'embedded_list': []},
 'jb234bhj23423h4b4': {'embedded_list': []},
    ... }
```

This will make all your desired operations much easier.  If the inner dictionaries only contain the embedded list, this can be further simplified to

```
{'234nj233nkj2k4n52': [],
 'jb234bhj23423h4b4': [],
    ... }
```

Now, all you need is a `collections.defaultdict(list)`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
d['234nj233nkj2k4n52'].append(whatever)
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I completely missed the fact I didn't actually need to main list.  I'll mark this as the answer when the time runs out.

Answer (score 1):

or just a simple dic

```
{
  '234nj233nkj2k4n52' : [],
  'jb234bhj23423h4b4' : []
}
```